# How to make such a header in CSS

Tags: css

I need an idea how to make such a header in css. Usualy I make such a things by setting up backgroud behind the text and moving the text up by negative margin. But here I have a background image behind. Any ideas pls...[image]

Comment: Please show relevant code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this. As it stands I don't understand why you can't have both your background image and a linear-gradient making the line.

Comment: A linear gradient! Thank you, this worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

one idea can be to use hr in a div to draw line

```css
.inline hr {
  width:40%;
}


.inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  <hr/>
  <span>14 days trial</span>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with

```
<div class= 'container'>
  <div class="image1">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="image2">
    <img src="" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

and than apply

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Horrible markup. No need for all these divs, you can put the classes directly on the `img` and `p` tags. From semantic way, the lines should be a background image and not an actual `img`.

Comment: yes you can do it without divs,  but i don't understand why the lines should be a background image from semantic way? can you explain pls @cloned and FYI img's are not a good elements to deal i prefer inside divs. you can just leave alt=""

Comment: Thanks for an idea. And yes, there is no need to upload one more image. We'd better use div backgrounds or border instead!

Answer (score 0):

Another Idea.

```css
 
    
hr.right {
    float:right;
    width:40%;

}

hr.left{
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    max-width

}

img {
    background-size:cover;
    height:100px;
    width:100%; 
    top:0;
    }
 
.myheader {
   top:80px;
   position:relative;
   overflow:overlay;
   }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="myheader"><hr class="left">MY TEXT HERE<hr class="right"></div> 
    <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/watercolor-poppy-bottom-border-horizontal-floral-background-abstract-pink-flowers-leaves-white-botanical-illustration-180021083.jpg">          
</div>
```